# Ignoring a light source in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting

I'm trying to make a 3D hex grid and I want to implement a fog of war.

Here's a sample of what the grid looks like at the moment:

[image: three.js hex grid]

I have lighting set up as follows:

```
// hemisphere light
var hemisphereLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0.3);
scene.add(hemisphereLight);

// point light
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.7);
pointLight.position = camera.position;
pointLight.rotation.y = Math.PI/2;
scene.add(pointLight);
```

What I'm trying to do is to make tiles that are in the fog of war not respond to the `pointLight`, that way they only have the low intensity `hemisphereLight`. I can't seem to find a way to do this. I can't change the tiles to use `MeshBasicMaterial`, which doesn't respond to any lights, because I DO want the "fog of war" tiles to have the lighting from `hemisphereLight`.

I'm open to suggestions to implement fog of war differently as well.

UPDATE:

I was able to get it to work using a custom shader.

[image: Finished fog of war]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice concept, IMHO.

Really, your only choice is to create your own `ShaderMaterial` for the "fog of war" tiles. In your shader, you would ignore all lights that are not `HemisphereLights`.

Remember, if you are going to use `ShaderMaterial`, and you want to be able to access the scene lights, you need to set the material parameter `lights: true`. There are many three.js examples of this.

three.js r.58

Comment: Do you have a link to an example that can help me? I haven't worked with `ShaderMaterial` at all and I'm having trouble finding an example that helps me.

Comment: Simple example of shader, but without accessing the three.js lights: http://jsfiddle.net/XGWGn/. For your purpose, this may be ok -- you can hack in your own fake light in the shader. Unfortunatley, the three.js examples that access the scene lights are much more complicated, and you will just have to put in a lot of effort to understand them.

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work, thanks for your help!
http://i.imgur.com/qwNtzHo.jpg